# Go run loop in parallel with timeout

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

I need to run the requests in `parallel` and not one after another but with timeout. now can I do it in go ?

This is the specific code which I need to run in **parallel** and the trick here is also to use timeout, i.e. wait to all the request according to the timeout and get the responses after all finished.

```
    for _, test := range testers {
        checker := NewTap(test.name, test.url, test.timeout)
        res, err := checker.Check()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(res.name)
        fmt.Println(res.res.StatusCode)

    }
```

This is the all code (working code)
https://play.golang.org/p/cXnJJ6PW_CF

```
package main

import (
    `fmt`
    `net/http`
    `time`
)

type HT interface {
    Name() string
    Check() (*testerResponse, error)
}

type testerResponse struct {
    name string
    res  http.Response
}

type Tap struct {
    url     string
    name    string
    timeout time.Duration
    client  *http.Client
}

func NewTap(name, url string, timeout time.Duration) *Tap {
    return &Tap{
        url:    url,
        name:   name,
        client: &http.Client{Timeout: timeout},
    }
}

func (p *Tap) Check() (*testerResponse, error) {
    response := &testerResponse{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", p.url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    res, e := p.client.Do(req)
    response.name = p.name
    response.res = *res
    if err != nil {
        return response, e
    }
    return response, e
}

func (p *Tap) Name() string {
    return p.name
}

func main() {

    var checkers []HT

    testers := []Tap{
        {
            name:    "first call",
            url:     "http://stackoverflow.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 20,
        },
        {
            name:    "second call",
            url:     "http://www.example.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 10,
        },
    }

    for _, test := range testers {
        checker := NewTap(test.name, test.url, test.timeout)
        res, err := checker.Check()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(res.name)
        fmt.Println(res.res.StatusCode)

        checkers = append(checkers, checker)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A popular concurrency pattern in Go is using worker pools.

A basic worker pool uses two channels; one to put jobs on, and another to read results to. In this case, our jobs channel will be of type `Tap` and our results channel will be of type `testerResponse`.

### Workers

take a job from the jobs channel and puts the result on the results channel.

```golang
// worker defines our worker func. as long as there is a job in the
// "queue" we continue to pick up  the "next" job
func worker(jobs <-chan Tap, results chan<- testerResponse) {
    for n := range jobs {
        results <- n.Check()
    }
}
```

### Jobs

to add jobs, we need to iterate over our `testers` and put them on our jobs channel.

```golang
// makeJobs fills up our jobs channel
func makeJobs(jobs chan<- Tap, taps []Tap) {
    for _, t := range taps {
        jobs <- t
    }
}
```

### Results

In order to read results, we need to iterate over them.

```golang
// getResults takes a job from our worker pool and gets the result
func getResults(tr <-chan testerResponse, taps []Tap) {
    for range taps {
        r := <- tr
        status := fmt.Sprintf("'%s' to '%s' was fetched with status '%d'\n", r.name, r.url, r.res.StatusCode)
        if r.err != nil {
            status = fmt.Sprintf(r.err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Println(status)
    }
}
```

Finally, our main function.

```golang
func main() {
    // Make buffered channels
    buffer := len(testers)
    jobsPipe := make(chan Tap, buffer)               // Jobs will be of type `Tap`
    resultsPipe := make(chan testerResponse, buffer) // Results will be of type `testerResponse`

    // Create worker pool
    // Max workers default is 5
    // maxWorkers := 5
    // for i := 0; i < maxWorkers; i++ {
    //  go worker(jobsPipe, resultsPipe)
    // }

    // the loop above is the same as doing:
    go worker(jobsPipe, resultsPipe)
    go worker(jobsPipe, resultsPipe)
    go worker(jobsPipe, resultsPipe)
    go worker(jobsPipe, resultsPipe)
    go worker(jobsPipe, resultsPipe)
    // ^^ this creates 5 workers..

    makeJobs(jobsPipe, testers)
    getResults(resultsPipe, testers)
}
```

### Putting it all together

I changed the timeout to one millisecond for the 'second call' to show how the timeout works.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type HT interface {
    Name() string
    Check() (*testerResponse, error)
}

type testerResponse struct {
    err  error
    name string
    res  http.Response
    url  string
}

type Tap struct {
    url     string
    name    string
    timeout time.Duration
    client  *http.Client
}

func NewTap(name, url string, timeout time.Duration) *Tap {
    return &Tap{
        url:    url,
        name:   name,
        client: &http.Client{Timeout: timeout},
    }
}

func (p *Tap) Check() testerResponse {
    fmt.Printf("Fetching %s %s \n", p.name, p.url)
    // theres really no need for NewTap
    nt := NewTap(p.name, p.url, p.timeout)
    res, err := nt.client.Get(p.url)
    if err != nil {
        return testerResponse{err: err}
    }

    // need to close body
    res.Body.Close()
    return testerResponse{name: p.name, res: *res, url: p.url}
}

func (p *Tap) Name() string {
    return p.name
}

// makeJobs fills up our jobs channel
func makeJobs(jobs chan<- Tap, taps []Tap) {
    for _, t := range taps {
        jobs <- t
    }
}

// getResults takes a job from our jobs channel, gets the result, and
// places it on the results channel
func getResults(tr <-chan testerResponse, taps []Tap) {
    for range taps {
        r := <-tr
        status := fmt.Sprintf("'%s' to '%s' was fetched with status '%d'\n", r.name, r.url, r.res.StatusCode)
        if r.err != nil {
            status = fmt.Sprintf(r.err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Printf(status)
    }
}

// worker defines our worker func. as long as there is a job in the
// "queue" we continue to pick up  the "next" job
func worker(jobs <-chan Tap, results chan<- testerResponse) {
    for n := range jobs {
        results <- n.Check()
    }
}

var (
    testers = []Tap{
        {
            name:    "1",
            url:     "http://google.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 20,
        },
        {
            name:    "2",
            url:     "http://www.yahoo.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 10,
        },
        {
            name:    "3",
            url:     "http://stackoverflow.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 20,
        },
        {
            name:    "4",
            url:     "http://www.example.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 10,
        },
        {
            name:    "5",
            url:     "http://stackoverflow.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 20,
        },
        {
            name:    "6",
            url:     "http://www.example.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 10,
        },
        {
            name:    "7",
            url:     "http://stackoverflow.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 20,
        },
        {
            name:    "8",
            url:     "http://www.example.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 10,
        },
        {
            name:    "9",
            url:     "http://stackoverflow.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 20,
        },
        {
            name:    "10",
            url:     "http://www.example.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 10,
        },
        {
            name:    "11",
            url:     "http://stackoverflow.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 20,
        },
        {
            name:    "12",
            url:     "http://www.example.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 10,
        },
        {
            name:    "13",
            url:     "http://stackoverflow.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 20,
        },
        {
            name:    "14",
            url:     "http://www.example.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 10,
        },
    }
)

func main() {
    // Make buffered channels
    buffer := len(testers)
    jobsPipe := make(chan Tap, buffer)               // Jobs will be of type `Tap`
    resultsPipe := make(chan testerResponse, buffer) // Results will be of type `testerResponse`

    // Create worker pool
    // Max workers default is 5
    // maxWorkers := 5
    // for i := 0; i < maxWorkers; i++ {
    //  go worker(jobsPipe, resultsPipe)
    // }

    // the loop above is the same as doing:
    go worker(jobsPipe, resultsPipe)
    go worker(jobsPipe, resultsPipe)
    go worker(jobsPipe, resultsPipe)
    go worker(jobsPipe, resultsPipe)
    go worker(jobsPipe, resultsPipe)
    // ^^ this creates 5 workers..

    makeJobs(jobsPipe, testers)
    getResults(resultsPipe, testers)
}
```

Which outputs:

```golang
// Fetching http://stackoverflow.com 
// Fetching http://www.example.com 
// Get "http://www.example.com": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
// 'first call' to 'http://stackoverflow.com' was fetched with status '200'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222388/discussion-on-answer-by-matt-oestreich-go-run-loop-in-parallel-with-timeout).

Answer (score 1):

Parallelism can be done in different ways in Golang.
This is a naive approach with wait group, Mutex and unlimited go routines which is not recommended.
I think using channels is the preferred way to do parallelism.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type HT interface {
    Name() string
    Check() (*testerResponse, error)
}

type testerResponse struct {
    name string
    res  http.Response
}

type Tap struct {
    url     string
    name    string
    timeout time.Duration
    client  *http.Client
}

func NewTap(name, url string, timeout time.Duration) *Tap {
    return &Tap{
        url:  url,
        name: name,
        client: &http.Client{
            Timeout: timeout,
        },
    }
}

func (p *Tap) Check() (*testerResponse, error) {
    response := &testerResponse{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", p.url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    res, e := p.client.Do(req)
    if e != nil {
        return response, e
    }
    response.name = p.name
    response.res = *res

    return response, e
}

func (p *Tap) Name() string {
    return p.name
}

func main() {

    var checkers []HT
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    locker := sync.Mutex{}

    testers := []Tap{
        {
            name:    "first call",
            url:     "http://google.com",
            timeout: time.Second * 20,
        },
        {
            name:    "second call",
            url:     "http://www.example.com",
            timeout: time.Millisecond * 100,
        },
    }

    for _, test := range testers {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(tst Tap) {
            defer wg.Done()
            checker := NewTap(tst.name, tst.url, tst.timeout)
            res, err := checker.Check()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            fmt.Println(res.name)
            fmt.Println(res.res.StatusCode)
            locker.Lock()
            defer locker.Unlock()
            checkers = append(checkers, checker)
        }(test)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, two questions :) 1. where do you refer to the `timeout` ? 2. so you suggest to use channel instead sync.Mutex{},why?

Comment: `context` provides timeouts, cancels and channels about it.

Comment: I added the timeout to the http client (NewTap function).
It's not optimal because it's safe to reuse client. I think you can create client for each time out and use it with all requests with the same timeout.

Comment: @RaynD I'm close to having something for you!